# Directive not working in IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called barsMax and it is not working in IE8, even if I already placed:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> 
  <script> 
   document.createElement('bars-max'); 
  </script> 
<![endif]-->
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is polyfill called before angular introduced in page?

Comment: any js snippet that tries to make older browsers conform to newer standards

Comment: yes, I already tried placing it in the top most part of the head of my Layout.cshtml, it still doesn't work...I also tried placing it in the top most part of my index.cshtml..nothing happens

Comment: my directive is being loaded.. but the ng-class within the directive doesn't work...do i need another polyfill to make ng-class work

Comment: shouldn't...best thing would be create a demo in jsfiddle that replicates problem  and can be inspected in a browser console. Are you sure class not working and it's not just a css rules priority problem?

Comment: here is the fiddle...works perfectly fine in chrome...but not in ie

 jsfiddle.net/tphalp/jGvsW/

Answer (score 0):

Code you are using also has a pseudo tag `bars-current`.

Adding `document.createElement('bars-current');` to your polyfill worked for me.

*DISCLAMER : Am Using IE10 in IE8 standards mode but error thrown in console if don't create elements first and jsfiddle itself falls apart without it in IE8*

<kbd>**[DEMO Working version](http://jsfiddle.net/jGvsW/19/)**</kbd>

Comment: I am using ie9 in ie8 and I can't run jsfiddle in IE.May I know how you made it work? My other problem is that when I change the data in my scope, the css no longer works in IE but on initial load...it works

Comment: This is another fiddle to demonstrate what I am working on... http://jsfiddle.net/jGvsW/20/

Comment: It works in chrome but not in IE...what happens in IE is that... example may previous max:100 and current: 100 then the gray bar would have a width of 100px and the colored bar will have a width of 100px. The color of the colored bar will be green since current is equal to max... and then I updated the scope.changeability to max: 130 and current:90 so I should expect that the gray bar will have a width of 130px and the colored bar should have a width of 90px but the width does not update. The color is correct. The problem is the width because it does not update. Thanks Charlie

Comment: stilll not creating the other pseudo tag in IE conditional. Modify demos to include it so others can help also. What heppens in the demo I created that does have it?  I didn't play with it much...just looked at initial load

Comment: on initial load, it worked but when I already tried changing the values of max and current, the width stays the same

Comment: still not creating the other pseudo tag in IE conditional -->> Do you mean this one? <!--[if lte IE 8]> 
  <script> 
   document.createElement('bars-max'); 
  </script> 
<![endif]--> ... I already added it

Comment: no......also need `document.createElement('bars-current')`. Look in console for erorrs in IE....will be something like `Unexpected call to method or property access.undefined ` when you don't create the tags

Comment: I threw a new fiddle..this is the actual thing that I am working on and it only needs the bar-max fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jGvsW/20/

Answer (score 0):

IE doesnt allow unfamiliar tags and therefor you may not use directives as tags like . you must use restrict "A" and use it as an attribute in a known html tag. if you dont want the wrapper tag use replace:true like this

return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true,
        scope: ...,
        link:...
you can see some examples about all that here https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=949DC4EDBFFD4738!189&authkey=!ABZCTBTTOCDYGhk

working version tested in ie8 native http://jsbin.com/IDOMuqU/2/edit
(the not working version in ie8 native with the polyfills - http://jsbin.com/IDOMuqU/1/edit)

Comment: not entirely true if you use the polyfill OP is using in IE conditional...at least for IE8 and 9

Comment: i think this is still the problem because when angular renders itself he doesnt look at you polyfill...

Comment: angular doesn't ever know about the polyfill, nor does it need to...that is for the browser only and has nothing to do with angular . angular is manipulating the DOM...which is managed within the browser engine

Comment: added a jsbin to my answer, since the fiddle crashed in ie8