# angular js directive not working in IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I'm developing in Internet Explorer (10 and 11), and I keep having a problem when I have an angular directive in the HTML code. 
I created a directive called "control-number" just to check that there aren't any commas in de input:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('controlNumber', controlNumber);

  function controlNumber() {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
      element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.key === ',' || event.key === 'e' || event.key === 'E') {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input control-number type="text" maxlength="6" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="$ctrl.percentageAddonEntity.percentage">
```

In Chrome it works fine, no problem but in IE, it doesnt go into the directive. I tried with another name ("control" instead of "control-number"), moving the name directive to another place and just leaving the directive in the input () and it doesnt work.

Does anybody ever have had the same problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesnt go into the directive'? Is the directive compiled in the DOM?

Comment: Are there any `console.logs` displayed? `IE` is more strict then for instance `Chrome`.

Comment: You could try what this user did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611280/directive-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: You should use keyCode instead of key.

Comment: also ie does not support keypress, use keydown

Comment: I changed all of you told me but I think that's not the real problem I'm getting.